Blank White Space Under Footer (Wordpress Theme + Elementor)
I am working on a site using WordPress and Elementor. We installed a theme, however there seems to be an issue with scrolling and white space under the footer. When the page initially loads, everything is fine, however if you scroll down using the side scroll bar, then scroll back up (sometimes you have to do it a couple of times), a huge white space is created under the footer.
I have checked the developer tools (I am using Google Chrome), however I cannot target the white space. If I highlight the body, it shows the main container should stop. I have set the overflow to hidden, but this did not work.
If you look at the screenshot, I am highlighting the full html container but cannot target the white space. If you notice the scroll bar shows there is a TON of white space under it (thousands of pixels). The strange thing is when the page initially loads, the scroll bar is bigger, indicating it is a smaller page, however when the bug happens, the scroll bar gets smaller and I can scroll through all of the white space below the footer. Any thoughts?
URL:
https://www.honesttimesharetransfer.com/
I have tried to set the overflow of the main body to hidden, but it did not work.enter image description here

Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] here. After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [mre] for debugging details. Please also read: Can I just post a link

It looks like your "Client Feedback & Reviews" carousel is causing issues, but as Howard E pointed out with "Can I just post a link," a linked website or code will change over time. It may be different than how it was now from yesterday when you posted your link and my recommendation may now be moot.
